# Highstock: How can I format the xAxis crosshair label?

Tags: highcharts, format, cross-hair-label, x-axis

I try to format the xAxis crosshair label, but the default one always overlap the formatted one. In the example, how can I have only the RED label? Or in other words, how can we format this xAxis crosshair label with HighStock (the behaviour seems to be different from HighCharts).

Second question: Why do the xAxis labels show 0,1,2,3, and not 1,2,3,4 as specified in the serie?

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Price'
    },
    ordinal: false,
     labels: {   formatter: function () {return this.value;}},
    crosshair: {
      width: 0.5,
      color: 'black',
      label: {
        backgroundColor:  'rgb(255,0,0)',
        formatter: function (value) {
          return 'this is a long label: '+value;
        },
        enabled: true,
        padding: 8
      }
    }
  },

  yAxis: {
      labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value + ' units';
            }
        }
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false
    },
    navigator: {
        enabled: false
    },

   series: [{
        type: 'areaspline',
        data: [['1',1],['2',3],['3',1],['4',4]]
    }]
});
```

Here JSFiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Francois_G/xjL7yc03/27/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second label is a tooltip header, to disable it set:

```
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: ''
    }
```

As to your second question: strings in your data format are treated as point names, so instead of:

```
data: [
  ['1', 1],
  ...
]
```

Set:

```
data: [
  [1, 1],
  ...
]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1g4m2ka8/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.headerFormat